# How to colour line connecting markers differently to the markers in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to make the lines connecting the markers of my plot red and keep the markers blue. Here is my tex so far.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    xlabel={Frequency(Hz)},
    ylabel={Phase shift (degrees)},
    xmin=0, xmax=20000,
    ymin=-95, ymax=10,
    xtick={0,100,1000,10000},
    ytick={10,0,-10,-20,-30,-40,-50,-60,-70,-80,-90},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (100,-11.52)(1000,-64.8)(2000,-74.88)(4000,-92.16)(10000,-93.6)
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? Use `mark options={color=blue}` in `addplot` environment.

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shadows,intersections,positioning,calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    xlabel={Frequency(Hz)},
    ylabel={Phase shift (degrees)},
    xmin=0, xmax=20000,
    ymin=-95, ymax=10,
    xtick={0,100,1000,10000},
    ytick={10,0,-10,-20,-30,-40,-50,-60,-70,-80,-90},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=square,
    mark options={color=blue}
    ]
    coordinates {
    (100,-11.52)(1000,-64.8)(2000,-74.88)(4000,-92.16)(10000,-93.6)
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much exactly what I needed.

Comment: @TomFinet,  Your  welcome.